# After @keyframes animation over, javascript can not manipulate the css value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

Keyframes code below:

```
#animate{
        width:100px;
        height:100px;
        border:solid 1px #ccc;
        position:absolute;
    }
@keyframes slideMiddle{
    0%{
        left:20px;
    }
    100%{
        left:40px;
    }
}
.animate{slideMiddle,1s,both}
```

and then I add the class `animate` to the element `ele` via JavaScript, it works as I expect, but after animation done, I use JavaScript to set `ele.style.left="80px"`, nothing happen, the position of `ele` is same as before.

Then I modified class `animate` to `.animate{slideMiddle,1s}`, and also add `.animate` to ele, after animation done, it worked when I set `ele.style.left="80px"`.

So my question is:Does `animation-fill-mode:both;` prevent JavaScript manipulating the css property which animated in keyframe?

***Update***, here is my code:

HTML

```
<div id='animate'></div>
```

JS

```
var ele=document.getElementById('animate');
ele.classList.add('animate');
setTimeout(function(){
   ele.style.left='80px';
},5000);
```

I open the devtool in chrome to watch any changes would happen in `<div id='animate'></div>`, about 5s later, `ele` did change the inline `left` value to `80px`, but there is no change of it's position in page， this is weird. Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you sure you are applying the javascript AFTER the animation has finished? Show your JS code please.

Comment: please provide your full code

Comment: @Alex,@DCdaz Sorry to reply so late, I have updated my question :)